# PHP form checkbox

Tags: php, checkbox

I'm havig a really bad time with a checkbox contact form. Now If I click sent in my webpage I have this result in my email:

- Email: whatever@whatever.com
- Nombre: whatever
- Le interessa: (THIS IS
  CHECKBOX AND IT'S EMPTY VALUES. I WOULD LIKE TO TAKE THE CHOICES THAT THE USER MAKE)
- Otros intereses: whatever

Thank you, I'll apreciate some help

HTML->

```
<form name="form-contact-us" id="form-contact-us">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="txtName">Name: </label>
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Name"
                                            class="form-control required" id="txtName" name="txtName" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="txtEmail">Email:</label>
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail ID"
                                            class="form-control required email" id="txtEmail" name="txtEmail" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <label for="txtMessage">Información:</label><br>
                            ***<input type="checkbox" id="web" name="check[]" value="Creación de web"> 
                                    <label for="web">Creación de web</label><br>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="red" name="check[]" value="Gestión de reputación Online / Redes Sociales"> 
                                    <label for="red">Gestión de reputación Online / Redes Sociales</label><br>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="seo" name="check[]" value="Gestión Estratégica (SEO, e-mail marketing)"> 
                                    <label for="seo">Gestión Estratégica (SEO, e-mail marketing)</label><br><br>***
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="txtMessage">Otros:</label>
                                <textarea placeholder="Message" class="form-control required"
                                    id="txtMessage" name="txtMessage" rows="10"></textarea>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="txtCaptcha"></label>
                                <input
                                    type="text" class="form-control required captcha"
                                    placeholder="Are you human?" id="txtCaptcha" name="txtCaptcha" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="button" id="btn-Send" value="Send" class="btn btn-theme-inverse" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-12" id="contact-form-message"></div>
                        </form>
```

PHP->

```
<?php

    $formType = $_POST["formType"];
    $MailTo = 'victor.fernandez.gayan@gmail.com';

    $txtName = $_POST["txtName"];
    $txtEmail = $_POST["txtEmail"];
    $txtRating = "";
    $txtWebsite = "";
    $txtMessage = $_POST["txtMessage"];
    $putavariable = $_POST["check"];

    if(!(empty($_POST['check']))){
    foreach($_POST['check'] as $value){
        $check_msg .= "Persona interesada en: $value\n";
    }
    }
    if ($formType == "comments") {
        $txtWebsite = $_POST["txtWebsite"];
    }

    if ($formType == "reviews") {
        $txtRating = $_POST["txtRating"];
    }

    $success = TRUE;    

    try{
        if(trim($txtEmail)==NULL){
            throw new Exception("Please enter your e-mail id.");
        }
        else
        {
            if (!preg_match("/\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*/", trim($txtEmail)))
            {
                throw new Exception("Please enter the valid e-mail.");
            }
        }

        if(trim($txtName)==NULL){
            throw new Exception("Please enter your name.");
        }

        if(trim($txtMessage)==NULL){
            throw new Exception("Please enter your message.");
        }

        if($formType == "contact") {   
            $MailSubject = "New Contact Mail";
            $MailBody = "<strong>Email: </strong> ".$txtEmail."<br />";
            $MailBody .= "<strong>Nombre: </strong> ".$txtName."<br />";
            $MailBody .= "<strong>Le interessa: </strong> ".$putavariable."<br />";
            $MailBody .= "<strong>Otros intereses: </strong> ".$txtMessage."<br />";

        }

        if($formType == "comments") {   
            $MailSubject = "New Comment Mail";
            $MailBody = "<strong>Email: </strong> ".$txtEmail."<br />";
            $MailBody .= "<strong>Name: </strong> ".$txtName."<br />";
            $MailBody .= "<strong>Website: </strong> ".$txtWebsite."<br />";
            $MailBody .= "<strong>Comment: </strong> ".$txtMessage."<br />";

        }

        if($formType == "reviews") {   
            $MailSubject = "New Review Mail";
            $MailBody = "<strong>Email: </strong> ".$txtEmail."<br />";
            $MailBody .= "<strong>Name: </strong> ".$txtName."<br />";
            $MailBody .= "<strong>Rating: </strong> ".$txtRating."<br />";
            $MailBody .= "<strong>Review: </strong> ".$txtMessage."<br />";
        }

        $MailFrom = $txtEmail;

        $MailHeaders = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $MailHeaders .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

        $MailHeaders .= "From: <".$txtEmail.">"."\r\n";


        $result =  mail($MailTo, $MailSubject, $MailBody, $MailHeaders);

        if(!$result){
            throw new Exception("Email no enviado:(");
        }

        $success = TRUE;
    }
    catch (Exception $e){
        header("Status: 400 Bad Request", TRUE, 400);
        echo($e->getMessage());
        $success = FALSE;
    }

    if ($success)
    {
        header("Status: 200 OK", TRUE, 200);    
        // add your custom success message here
        echo("EMAIL ENVIADO :)");
    }
    else
    {
        header("Status: 400 Bad Request", TRUE, 400);

}
?>
```

Comment: Did you do a `var_dump($_POST);` ?

Comment: No I didn't. What do you mean?

Comment: Then you should. I may tell you if your checkboxes are actually posted . It tells you if your error is in your form or in your PHP. There is nearly no bug that can't be found with more var_dumps.

Comment: Ok then where I should add var_dump($_POST); in my code? Thanks

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` will show you the contents of your $_POST variable, that was filled from your form. So you need to put this line to a place where you expect it to already contain your form values, probably immediatly before your first access to this array.

Comment: As a result: array(5) { ["formType"]=> string(7) "contact" ["txtName"]=> string(5) "Check" ["txtEmail"]=> string(19) "cheking@cheking.com" ["txtMessage"]=> string(32) "I'm cheking where is the problem" ["txtMailTo"]=> string(0) "" } Definetly checkbox is not here so it must be some problem of php code. Some advice what to do now?

Comment: Nope. Since your $_POST does not contain your "check" array, it shows us that your form is not sending them. PHP can only process what it got, so error is in your form. Did you even check those checkboxes? A form will only send checkboxes that were checked!

Answer (score 0):

I revised my form:

```
<label for="txtMessage">Información:</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="web" name="check[]" value="Creación de web"> 
<label for="web">Creación de web</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="red" name="check[]" value="Gestión de reputación Online / Redes Sociales"> 
<label for="red">Gestión de reputación Online / Redes Sociales</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="seo" name="check[]" value="Gestión Estratégica (SEO, e-mail marketing)"> 
<label for="seo">Gestión Estratégica (SEO, e-mail marketing)</label><br><br>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="txtMessage">Otros:</label>
<textarea placeholder="Message" class="form-control required" id="txtMessage" name="txtMessage" rows="10"></textarea>
```

and PHP:

```
$formType = $_POST["formType"];
$MailTo = 'victor.fernandez.gayan@gmail.com';

$txtName = $_POST["txtName"];
$txtEmail = $_POST["txtEmail"];
$txtRating = "";
$txtWebsite = "";
$txtMessage = $_POST["txtMessage"];
$putavariable = $_POST["check"];

var_dump($_POST);
if(!(empty($_POST['check']))){
foreach($_POST['check'] as $value){
    $check_msg .= "Persona interesada en: $value\n";
}
}
```

And result:

```
array(5) { ["formType"]=> string(7) "contact" ["txtName"]=> string(10) "Imchecking" ["txtEmail"]=> string(25) "Imchecking@Imchecking.com" ["txtMessage"]=> string(16) "hello Imchecking" ["txtMailTo"]=> string(0) "" } EMAIL SENDED :)
```

I thing I'm close but I dont know how to procee it. I checked the checkboxes on before sent the email but nothing happens.